# Post-increment and Pre-decrement addressing modes on Intel 80386

Tags: assembly, x86, intel, addressing-mode

I know how these modes work on other processors, what I don't understand is why doesn´t the 80386 need the post-increment and pre-decrement addressing modes?

Also what´s the relation between these addressing modes and the `push` and `pop` instructions?

Comment: Do you have a question?  If yes, please edit your post to include a question.

Comment: almost no processor **needs** these modes (at least if it does have indirect addressing and basic arithmetic over general purpose registers). Although they may be handy, but when I'm coding x86 asm, I don't really miss these, one gets used to write the code in other way quickly (but x86 has also `lods`, `stos`, `movs` instructions, etc... so it's not like it lacks post/pre increments completely).

Comment: Most RISC machines don't have inc/dec addressing modes.  ARM is the exception, being less RISCy than MIPS, SPARC, and so on.

Comment: Also note that post increment and pre decrement get decoded into the same micro-ops as two separate instructions, so almost no impact on execution speed.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> why the 80386 doesn´t need the post-increment and pre-decrement
>   addressing modes?

You never really **need** post-increment and pre-decrement addressing modes as long as you have `ADD`/`SUB` instructions. They're just convenience instructions.

> what´s the relation between this addressing modes and the push and pop
>   instructions?

`PUSH` is pre-decrement save and `POP` is post-increment load.

Comment: ARM pre/post-increment (with an explicit offset, so it can be negative for pre/post-decrement) is supported directly in the machine code, *not* as a pseudo-instruction (multiple machine instructions from one asm source line).  ftp://www.cs.uregina.ca/pub/class/301/ARM-addressing/lecture.html.  Apparently `VLDR` with post-increment is a pseudo-instruction for `vldm` (vector load multiple), though.  http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.dui0204j/CJADEFGH.html